# Overly-pedantic edits for spelling, usage, and grammar?

Tags: discussion

Is there a group opinion (or should there be one) about this situation? I've noticed a user who has a history of editing other people's questions, some of them months old, to replace "javascript" with "JavaScript", or "sysadmin" with "systems administrators." This user also fixes a lot of spelling errors.

The prime issue for me is that it brings old questions, some of them already answered, back to the front page. But now I also see why my girlfriend hates it when I correct her grammar - it is a bit annoying.

Am I just being nitpicky and pedantic in response, or is this a behavior that should be discouraged? I'm not trying to snipe at this particular user, but if it furthers the discussion I can provide examples.

Comment: "Strunk & White" badge?

Comment: There is a Copy Editor badge, for 600 edits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The changing of javascript/sysadmin on front page questions fine ... otherwise I would say just leave it be they are acceptable phasings/spellings IMHO.

Grammar/spelling errors i have no problem with them being fixed at any point.

Comment: Agreed. Editing a post just to capitalize one or two letters, that's pointless. Fixing incorrect spelling/grammar/style, always good.

Answer (score 3):

Just because it's an old question, it doesn't mean the person actively went looking for it to change it.

The Community user bumps questions periodically and I know I will often retag them when they appear, and if I had the rep I would probably correct spelling too.

Problem is when this action is performed, it *looks like* I edited an old question, but truth is that it was already bought to the front page because Community bumped it. A couple more hours on the front page won't hurt IMHO.

Comment: Frequently when I am searching the site for something or other I come across a few questions/answers that need fixing.  I fix them when I see them, but I never search for things just to fix the case.

Comment: Agreed. I never search out posts for editing but when they're put in front of me and require editing I don't concern myself over when they were originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok to edit a question to make it a better question (regardless of whether it is editing spelling that's too bad to be readable or editing content for clarity).

Pedantically editing an otherwise perfectly phrased question to change 'javascript' to JavaScript is another matter; It isn't like this is improving either the question or how well the question will show on googbing searches. Of course that arguably makes changing "sysadmins" to "system administrators" a grey area.